# Change table of contents numbering without changing titles

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, titles, titlesec

I'm working on a latex project using the report document class.
I want to change the way the table of content numbering is made. I want to show only the corresponding number, as follow :

[image]

Yet, I also want to keep the headings in the text as they normally are and be able to make cross reference as follow :

[image]

So far, I managed to make the toc and headings appeared as I want, using the `titlesec` package. But then the cross reference is not working.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\LARGE\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}}{10pt}{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{The First Subsection}
\subsubsection{The First Subsubsection} \label{sec:first_subsection}
\section{The Second Section}
\subsection{The Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{The Second Subsubsection}
See section \ref{sec:first_subsection} \nameref{sec:first_subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can define the label format e.g. with `\labelformat{subsubsection}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd try and avoid code duplication, which is error prone (and, indeed, you seem to have forgotten a period after the paragraph numbers).

Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last, definitely after `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}

\newcommand{\thefullsection}{\thechapter.\thesection}
\newcommand{\thefullsubsection}{\thefullsection.\thesubsection}
\newcommand{\thefullsubsubsection}{\thefullsubsection.\thesubsubsection}
\newcommand{\thefullparagraph}{\thefullsubsubsection.\theparagraph}

\labelformat{section}{\thefullsection}
\labelformat{subsection}{\thefullsubsection}
\labelformat{subsubsection}{\thefullsubsubsection}
\labelformat{paragraph}{\thefullparagraph}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\LARGE\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thefullsection.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thefullsubsection.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thefullsubsubsection.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\thefullparagraph.}{10pt}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{The First Subsection} 
\subsubsection{The First Subsubsection} \label{sec:first_subsection}
\section{The Second Section}
\subsection{The Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{The Second Subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
See section \ref{sec:first_subsection} \nameref{sec:first_subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Solution based on [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) comment :

Just use `\labelformat` command to redefine the way the reference is made

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\labelformat{subsubsection}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\LARGE\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}}{10pt}{}

% Added line
\labelformat{subsubsection}{\Roman{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{The First Subsection} 
\subsubsection{The First Subsubsection} \label{sec:first_subsection}
\section{The Second Section}
\subsection{The Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{The Second Subsubsection}
See section \ref{sec:first_subsection} \nameref{sec:first_subsection}

\end{document}
```

This could be extend to chapters, sections, subsections, paragraphs etc. using the same method.